# Gesture controlled robotic arm

Tags: arduino, sensor, fpga, raspberry-pi, robotics

Can I use gryometers and accelerometers to map the movement of a human arm and then apply it on a robot? The idea that I have is to collect the data from multiple sensors using Raspberry Pi and transmit over to another module via Bluetooth or local WiFi, there the data is translated back and used to drive motors in the robot to mimic basic movements such as walking or flexing of arms. Can the same also be achieved using arduino or FPGA boards?

Comment: 3d animation tracking techniques could be an alternative solution for obtaining movement data.

Answer (score 2):

What you are really asking is whether you can determine human arm position by inertial navigation from gyro and accelerometer data.

The answer is yes, but only for a few seconds until the errors get so large that the result is unusable.  Position is the second integral of acceleration.  Any offset error in a acceleration value becomes a linearly increasing error in velocity, which becomes a position error that grows with the square of time.

I once worked on a device to track your head movements during a golf swing.  It worked well enough for the length of a swing, but the data got useless fast after a couple of seconds or so.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain the required data with sufficient accuracy for movements upto 10 seconds?

Comment: @Shah: Probably not for a price you're willing to pay.  If you can measure joint angles directly, then you don't have to integrate anything, and there won't be steadily accumulating error.

Comment: Angular position sensor?

Comment: It's not actually acceleration you're interested in,  it's the first derivitave,  or "jerk"  the rate of change of acceleration.  Which is less easy to obtain and use.

Comment: @Tom: No, he ultimately wants to make a robot mimic a human.  That means he really wants position information, or at least angular position of all degrees of freedom of the joints.  Jerk is even worse than acceleration because it requires a triple integral to get position, as opposed to double integral to get position from acceleration.

Comment: Oh yuck.  I tried to get gesture driven arduino control working last year with some of my students and found it was effectively a complete waste of time.  We concluded that a Kinect approach would have been better.